# Building a self-executable JAR with Gradle and Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, gradle, uberjar, fatjar

I've written a simple Kotlin source file in order to get started, and a Gradle script file.
But I can't figure out how to add the main function to the manifest, so that the JAR could be self-executable.

Here is my build.gradle script :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:0.9.66'
    }
}
apply plugin: "kotlin"
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:0.9.66'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.loloof64.kotlin.exps.ExpsPackage'
    }
}
```

Here is my *com.loloof64.kotlin.exps.Multideclarations.kt*:

```kotlin
package com.loloof64.kotlin.exps

class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String) {
    fun component1(): String {
        return firstName
    }
    fun component2(): String {
        return lastName
    }
}

fun main(args: Array < String > ) {
    val(first, last) = Person("Laurent", "Bernabé")
    println("First name : $first - Last name : $last")
}
```

When I launch the JAR from terminal (`java -jar MYJar.jar`) I get the following stack trace, saying that the Kotlin reflection library classes are missing, and indeed they have not been added to the JAR. It seems that I am missing the *kotlin-compiler* artifact classes from the final JAR, and also the *kotlin-stdlib* sources, but I don't know how to adapt the Gradle build.

```
$> java -jar build/libs/kotlin_exps.jar 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/InternalPackage
    at com.loloof64.kotlin.exps.ExpsPackage.<clinit>(MultiDeclarations.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.InternalPackage
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

I am using Kotlin 0.9.66 and Gradle 2.1.

Comment: Note that the classname generated by Kotlin for a top-level function such as `main` is the package defined in the same file, plus the filename with `KT` appended.  In your case this would be `com.loloof64.kotlin.exps.MultideclarationsKT`.  You can change this behavior by adding to the top of the file `@file:JvmName("OtherName")` to define a new classname for all top-level functions in a file.

Comment: You append the two characters `Kt` not `KT`... that is upper case K and lower case t.  It is an easy error to make, but will cause the jar execution to fail.  I had this problem myself on occasion due to imperfect typing.

Comment: See [this rather comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71092054/8583692).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've found the workaround (thanks to [MkYong website](http://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies/))

1. The gradle script needed the kotlin-compiler artifact as a dependency
2. The gradle script needed a way to collect all kotlin files and put them into the jar.

So i get with the following gradle script :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
       classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.0.1-2'
    }
}

apply plugin: "kotlin"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.1-2'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.loloof64.kotlin.exps.MultideclarationsKT'
    }

    // NEW LINE HERE !!!
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

Comment: for me it worked without the compiler dependency, collecting the files for the jar was enough

Comment: Can confirm that the compiler dependency is not needed, collecting the files is enough.

Comment: Where is the jar after executing the task?

Comment: Placement of the jar file depends on the method to build the jar.  If you execute the gradle jar task it is put into the directory `build/libs`.  The build directory is at the same level as the `build.gradle` file.  If you construct the jar mapping inside the IntelliJ IDE as an artifact and build the artifact with IntelliJ, then it is placed inside the `out/artifacts` directory at the level of the IntelliJ project

Comment: Specifically, I found that after adding this jar_block to the build.gradle file, then I could create a successful jar either using the IntelliJ artifact mechanism or by building the jar file with gradle task mechanism.

Answer (score 38):

Add the plugin `application`, then set the `mainClassName` as

```
mainClassName = '[your_namespace].[your_arctifact]Kt'
```

For instance, suppose you have placed the following code in a file named `main.kt`:

```
package net.mydomain.kotlinlearn

import kotlin
import java.util.ArrayList

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    println("Hello!")

}
```

your `build.gradle` should be:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "net.mydomain.kotlinlearn.MainKt"
```

In fact *Kotlin* is building a class to encapsulate your main function named with the same name of your file - with Title Case.

Comment: Can you update your answer to the new naming convention for the how Kotlin creates classes for toplevel functions.  In his example, that would now be:  `com.loloof64.kotlin.exps.MultideclarationsKT` as the classname.  This is true for Kotlin 1.0 beta and beyond.

Comment: Updated for Kotlin 1.0 Beta and newer. Thanks Jayson.

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer; it's correct but not the full picture: It's required to 'collect' the Kotlin runtime files to make a complete executable jar, as below in @loloof64 's example.

Comment: This does not work anymore. I'll remove my downvote if you fix it.

Comment: @AdamArold I tested with 1.1.51 and it works. What version are you referring to? Thx

Comment: I'm using `1.1.4-3`.

Answer (score 22):

None of the above solution worked for me while building Artifact.

**IDE version `IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.1`**.

To fix the issue, do the following

**Steps**

**Step 1 - Create Artifact**

1. Go to *File -> Project Structure -> Artifacts*
2. Click the *`+` -> `JAR` -> `From modules with dependencies`*

[image]

3. Select your program's `Main Class`

[image]

**Step 2 - Change MANIFEST Path**

4. Change value of `Directory for META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` to your project root.

   For example , from  `/your/project/directory/src/main/kotlin` to `/your/project/directory`

[image]

5. Press `OK`,then Press `Apply` and `OK`.

**Step 3 - Build Artifact**

6. Finally, Go to *`Build` -> `Build Artifacts` -> `[your-artifact-name]` -> `Build`.*

The generated `JAR` file can be found in the `out/artifact/[your-artifact-name]` directory. (y)

Comment: Thank you very much!!! After several attempts, that was the only thing that worked for me!

Comment: Kotlin is such a cool language, but it has a horrendous build system (magic recepies all around). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

This is for [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.kts).
Note that the first 3 methods here modify the existing `Jar` task of Gradle.

#### Method 1: Placing library files beside the result JAR

This method does not need `application` or any other plugins.

```kotlin
tasks.jar {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.MyMainClass"
    manifest.attributes["Class-Path"] = configurations
        .runtimeClasspath
        .get()
        .joinToString(separator = " ") { file ->
            "libs/${file.name}"
        }
}
```

Note that Java requires us to use relative URLs for the `Class-Path` attribute. So, we cannot use the absolute path of Gradle dependencies (which is also prone to being changed and not available on other systems). If you want to use absolute paths, maybe [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47961942/8583692) will work.

Create the JAR with the following command:

```bash
./gradlew jar
```

The result JAR will be created in *build/libs/* directory by default.

After creating your JAR, copy your library JARs in *libs/* sub-directory of where you put your result JAR. Make sure your library JAR files do not contain space in their file name (their file name should match the one specified by `${file.name}` variable above in the task).

#### Method 2: Embedding the libraries in the result JAR file (fat or uber JAR)

This method too does not need any Gradle plugin.

```kotlin
tasks.jar {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.MyMainClass"
    val dependencies = configurations
        .runtimeClasspath
        .get()
        .map(::zipTree) // OR .map { zipTree(it) }
    from(dependencies)
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}
```

Creating the JAR is exactly the same as the previous method.

#### Method 3: Using the [Shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) (to create a fat or uber JAR)

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "6.0.0"
}
// Shadow task depends on Jar task, so these configs are reflected for Shadow as well
tasks.jar {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "org.example.MainKt"
}
```

Create the JAR with this command:

```bash
./gradlew shadowJar
```

See [Shadow documentations](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/#configuring-the-jar-manifest) for more information about configuring the plugin.

#### Method 4: Creating a new task (instead of modifying the `Jar` task)

```kotlin
tasks.create("MyFatJar", Jar::class) {
    group = "my tasks" // OR, for example, "build"
    description = "Creates a self-contained fat JAR of the application that can be run."
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.MyMainClass"
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    val dependencies = configurations
        .runtimeClasspath
        .get()
        .map(::zipTree)
    from(dependencies)
    with(tasks.jar.get())
}
```

## Running the created JAR

```bash
java -jar my-artifact.jar
```

The above solutions were tested with:

- Java 17
- Gradle 7.1 (which uses Kotlin 1.4.31 for *.kts* build scripts)

See the official [Gradle documentation for creating uber (fat) JARs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:creating_uber_jar_example).
For more information about manifests, see [Oracle Java Doc: Working with Manifest files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html).
For difference between `tasks.create()` and `tasks.register()` see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53654412/8583692).

Note that your [resource files will be included in the JAR file automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24724383/8583692) (assuming they were placed in */src/main/resources/* directory or any custom directory set as resources root in the build file). To access a resource file in your application, use this code (note the `/` at the start of names):

- Kotlin

  ```kotlin
  val vegetables = MyClass::class.java.getResource("/vegetables.txt").readText()
  // Alternative ways:
  // val vegetables = object{}.javaClass.getResource("/vegetables.txt").readText()
  // val vegetables = MyClass::class.java.getResourceAsStream("/vegetables.txt").reader().readText()
  // val vegetables = object{}.javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/vegetables.txt").reader().readText()
  ```
- Java

  ```java
  var stream = MyClass.class.getResource("/vegetables.txt").openStream();
  // OR var stream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/vegetables.txt");

  var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
  var vegetables = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
  ```

Answer (score 2):

In case you happen to be dumb, like me:

Don't create your IntelliJ run configuration as an Application. IntelliJ will assume it's Java & it will never work. Instead, use the "Kotlin" entry.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, for me it worked adding the jar section

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.photofiles.Application'
    }

    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

No need for the application plugin.

Comment: The main-class name needs to end with `Kt`.  So above it should be `ApplicationKt`.

Answer (score 2):

If using `Gradle` with the `Kotlin` `DSL`, then my [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53807387/262852) question has an answer of:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.2.51"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "2.0.4"
}

group = "xxx.yyy"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

tasks.withType<ShadowJar> {

    manifest.attributes.apply {
        put("Implementation-Title", "Gradle Jar File Example")
        //put("Implementation-Version" version)
        put("Main-Class", "HelloKotlinWorld.App")
    }
```

Which is, I think, the simplest solution.  Oh, perhaps you're using just `Kotlin` itself and not the `DSL`.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using the Kotlin MP plugin here is your code

```
jvm{
    jvmJar {
        manifest{
            attributes 'Main-Class':'Class path here'
        }
    }

}
```