# How to create a fat JAR with Gradle Kotlin script?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, executable-jar, gradle-kotlin-dsl

As titled, I'd like to know how to modify the `gradle.build.kts` in order to have a task to create a unique `jar` with all the dependencies (kotlin lib included) inside.

I found this sample in Groovy:

```
//create a single Jar with all dependencies
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File Example',
            'Implementation-Version': version,
            'Main-Class': 'com.mkyong.DateUtils'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

But I have no idea how I could write that in kotlin, other than:

```
task("fatJar") {

}
```

Comment: Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21721119/8583692).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Building a self-executable jar with Gradle and Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469365/building-a-self-executable-jar-with-gradle-and-kotlin)

Answer (score 63):

Here is a version that does not use a plugin, more like the Groovy version.

```
import org.gradle.jvm.tasks.Jar

val fatJar = task("fatJar", type = Jar::class) {
    baseName = "${project.name}-fat"
    manifest {
        attributes["Implementation-Title"] = "Gradle Jar File Example"
        attributes["Implementation-Version"] = version
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.mkyong.DateUtils"
    }
    from(configurations.runtime.map({ if (it.isDirectory) it else zipTree(it) }))
    with(tasks["jar"] as CopySpec)
}

tasks {
    "build" {
        dependsOn(fatJar)
    }
}
```

[Also explained here](https://techdev.io/de/developer-blog/building-a-fat-jar-with-gradle-script-kotlin)

---

Some commenters pointed out that this does not work anymore with newer Gradle versions.
Update tested with Gradle 5.4.1:

```
import org.gradle.jvm.tasks.Jar

val fatJar = task("fatJar", type = Jar::class) {
    baseName = "${project.name}-fat"
    manifest {
        attributes["Implementation-Title"] = "Gradle Jar File Example"
        attributes["Implementation-Version"] = version
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.mkyong.DateUtils"
    }
    from(configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().map({ if (it.isDirectory) it else zipTree(it) }))
    with(tasks.jar.get() as CopySpec)
}

tasks {
    "build" {
        dependsOn(fatJar)
    }
}
```

Note the difference in `configurations.runtimeClasspath.get()` and `with(tasks.jar.get() as CopySpec)`.

Comment: He's not kidding. This should be added somewhere in https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/tree/master/samples

Comment: Note that in Gradle 5 you will have to replace `configurations.runtime.map` with `configurations.runtime.get().map` to avoid `unresolved reference: isDirectory`. See discussion [here](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/1082#issuecomment-433037363).

Comment: And also note that for Gradle 5.4 you will need to replace `with(tasks["jar"] as CopySpec)` with `with(getByName("jar") as CopySpec)`

Comment: @Laurence using Gradle 5.4 your suggested modification actually broke it for me. I got an error: `Cause: null cannot be cast to non-null type org.gradle.api.file.CopySpec`

Comment: In gradle 5.4.1 I had to replace `with(tasks["jar"] as CopySpec)` with `val jar: CopySpec by getting(Jar::class); with(jar)`

Comment: I also had to  `exclude("META-INF/*.RSA", "META-INF/*.SF", "META-INF/*.DSA", "META-INF/INDEX.LIST")` for the main class to be found in the jar

Comment: Have to use `duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE` inside the `fatJar` task or exclude some files to avoid failure - `LICENSE.txt` inside each `jar` dependency was getting included, which caused some errors.

Comment: Make sure that you also exclude `**.kotlin_metadata` if you want others to consume the fat JAR and receive IDE support. Otherwise the IDE will be unable to resolve references inside the fat JAR: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-25709

Comment: For who facing deprecated warning on `baseName` and `version` , use `archiveBaseName.set("")` and `archiveVersion` instead.

Comment: This does not work anymore for gradle 6.8

Comment: @Chris Try it with `attributes["Implementation-Version"] = archiveVersion` instead

Comment: As of Gradle 7.3.3, the `from(configurations...)` line being present results in this error: `Cannot change dependencies of dependency configuration ':jvmApi' after it has been included in dependency resolution.`

Comment: ...Although my problem might be that I'm trying to do this in a multiplatform project, and it looks like I might have the task defined in the wrong place (at the top level at the bottom of the file, instead of within the `kotlin { jvm { ... } }` block.

Answer (score 32):

Here are 4 ways to do this. Note that the first 3 methods modify the existing `Jar` task of Gradle.

#### Method 1: Placing library files beside the result JAR

This method does not need `application` or any other plugins.

```kotlin
tasks.jar {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.MyMainClass"
    manifest.attributes["Class-Path"] = configurations
        .runtimeClasspath
        .get()
        .joinToString(separator = " ") { file ->
            "libs/${file.name}"
        }
}
```

Note that Java requires us to use relative URLs for the `Class-Path` attribute. So, we cannot use the absolute path of Gradle dependencies (which is also prone to being changed and not available on other systems). If you want to use absolute paths, maybe [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47961942/8583692) will work.

Create the JAR with the following command:

```bash
./gradlew jar
```

The result JAR will be created in *build/libs/* directory by default.

After creating your JAR, copy your library JARs in *libs/* sub-directory of where you put your result JAR. Make sure your library JAR files do not contain space in their file name (their file name should match the one specified by `${file.name}` variable above in the task).

#### Method 2: Embedding the libraries in the result JAR file (fat or uber JAR)

This method too does not need any Gradle plugin.

```kotlin
tasks.jar {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.MyMainClass"
    val dependencies = configurations
        .runtimeClasspath
        .get()
        .map(::zipTree) // OR .map { zipTree(it) }
    from(dependencies)
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}
```

Creating the JAR is exactly the same as the previous method.

#### Method 3: Using the [Shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) (to create a fat or uber JAR)

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "6.0.0"
}
// Shadow task depends on Jar task, so these configs are reflected for Shadow as well
tasks.jar {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.MyMainClass"
}
```

Create the JAR with this command:

```bash
./gradlew shadowJar
```

See [Shadow documentations](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/#configuring-the-jar-manifest) for more information about configuring the plugin.

#### Method 4: Creating a new task (instead of modifying the `Jar` task)

```kotlin
tasks.create("MyFatJar", Jar::class) {
    group = "my tasks" // OR, for example, "build"
    description = "Creates a self-contained fat JAR of the application that can be run."
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.MyMainClass"
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    val dependencies = configurations
        .runtimeClasspath
        .get()
        .map(::zipTree)
    from(dependencies)
    with(tasks.jar.get())
}
```

## Running the created JAR

```bash
java -jar my-artifact.jar
```

The above solutions were tested with:

- Java 17
- Gradle 7.1 (which uses Kotlin 1.4.31 for *.kts* build scripts)

See the official [Gradle documentation for creating uber (fat) JARs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:creating_uber_jar_example).
For more info about manifests, see [Oracle Java Documentation: Working with Manifest files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html).
For difference between `tasks.create()` and `tasks.register()` see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53654412/8583692).

Your [resource files will be included in the JAR file automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24724383/8583692) (assuming they were placed in classpath: */src/main/resources/* directory or any custom directory set as resources root in the build file). Here is how to access a resource file in your code (note the `/` at the start of names):

- Kotlin

  ```kotlin
  val vegetables = MyClass::class.java.getResource("/vegetables.txt").readText()
  // Alternative ways:
  // val vegetables = object{}.javaClass.getResource("/vegetables.txt").readText()
  // val vegetables = MyClass::class.java.getResourceAsStream("/vegetables.txt").reader().readText()
  // val vegetables = object{}.javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/vegetables.txt").reader().readText()
  ```
- Java

  ```java
  var stream = MyClass.class.getResource("/vegetables.txt").openStream();
  // OR var stream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/vegetables.txt");

  var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
  var vegetables = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
  ```

Comment: how would you do this for variants, if one wants a slim jar, and,  opitonally a fat(ter) jar? am trying for plantuml, and it is either fat or slim - but no option to control it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about this.

Comment: it works fine like you posted, with the dedicated task, method 4. only thing i am wondering - how to sign the fat jar then, as the standard sign task would not find it.

Comment: Maybe [this Gradle guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/signing_plugin.html#sec:signing_tasks) can help you.

Comment: got an answer in the gradle forums:
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/build-variant-command-line/42193/8 . which now is in plantuml main gradle script, signing working.

Comment: Upvote for shadow plugin, which was frictionless with Kotlin

Answer (score 9):

Here is how to do it as of Gradle 6.5.1, Kotlin/Kotlin-Multiplatform 1.3.72, utilizing a build.gradle.kts file and without using an extra plugin which does seem unnecessary and problematic with multiplatform;

Note: in reality, few plugins work well with the multiplatform plugin from what I can tell, which is why I suspect its design philosophy is so verbose itself. It's actually fairly elegant IMHO, but not flexible or documented enough so it takes a ton of trial and error to setup even WITHOUT additional plugins.

Hope this helps others.

```
kotlin {
    jvm {
        compilations {
            val main = getByName("main")
            tasks {
                register<Jar>("fatJar") {
                    group = "application"
                    manifest {
                        attributes["Implementation-Title"] = "Gradle Jar File Example"
                        attributes["Implementation-Version"] = archiveVersion
                        attributes["Main-Class"] = "[[mainClassPath]]"
                    }
                    archiveBaseName.set("${project.name}-fat")
                    from(main.output.classesDirs, main.compileDependencyFiles)
                    with(jar.get() as CopySpec)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you getting "is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set" error than add "duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.WARN" line after "group = .."

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [ShadowJar plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) to build a fat jar:

```
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        gradleScriptKotlin()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(kotlinModule("gradle-plugin"))
        classpath("com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.3")
    }
}

apply {
    plugin("kotlin")
    plugin("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

val shadowJar: ShadowJar by tasks
shadowJar.apply {
    manifest.attributes.apply {
        put("Implementation-Title", "Gradle Jar File Example")
        put("Implementation-Version" version)
        put("Main-Class", "com.mkyong.DateUtils")
    }

    baseName = project.name + "-all"
}
```

Simply run the task with 'shadowJar'.

NOTE: This assumes you're using [GSK 0.7.0](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-script-kotlin/releases/tag/v0.7.0) (latest as of 02/13/2017).

Comment: Not working, in the first line `import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar`, `ShadowJar` is unresolved..

Comment: Have you tried my answer since? I have it tested and working. I think the original problem was that the() required an extension class.

Comment: I tried it again [right now](http://imgur.com/qUozPd2), on the `tasks` it says `[DELEGATE_SPECIAL_FUNCTION_MISSING] Missing 'getValue(Build_gradle, KProperty<*>)' method on delegate of type 'TaskContainer!'`

Comment: Hm, are you on the latest GSK for sure? Compiler and plugin too?

Comment: I am on the last one [here](https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/dist-snapshots/). How can I check compiler and plugin? Could you give a try yourself [here](https://github.com/java-graphics/assimp)? I don't know, maybe I am missing some basic step somewhere..

Comment: I took a look and saw that you weren't on the newest dev version of GSK, but rather the most recent stable version. To take advantage of task delegation as outlined above, you'll need to update your gradle distributionUrl.

Once I cloned your repo and updated that, it all worked. You can find the latest releases for GSK here: https://github.com/gradle/gradle-script-kotlin/releases

Comment: Just tried once again, GSK 0.8.0, [same result](http://imgur.com/VvfCPWq)

Answer (score 2):

Wow, the above answers and comments to this now 7-year-old question saved my sanity ... I've upvoted all above who helped me realize the bare-bones build.gradle.kts below - thank you all for contributing!

This is for a build of an AWS Lambda using their Kotlin SDK, running by their Java 21 runtime on the arm64 architecture. The .jar to upload to said AWS Lambda is built from the command line with Gradle 8.5:

> >gradle awsJar

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.20"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("aws.sdk.kotlin:aws-core-jvm:0.35.0-beta")
    implementation("aws.sdk.kotlin:s3:0.35.0-beta")

    implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:1.2.3")
    implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-events:3.11.3")

    runtimeOnly("com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-log4j2:1.5.1")
}

kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(21)
}

task("awsJar", type = Jar::class) {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.Handler.handleRequest"
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    from(configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().map { if (it.isDirectory()) it else zipTree(it) })
    with(tasks.jar.get() as CopySpec)
}
```