# How to build a runnable ShadowJar with a gradle script Kotlin build file?

Tags: gradle, build, kotlin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Simplest possible Kotlin [hello world for gradle script Kotlin](http://thufir@dur:~/github/gradleScriptKotlin$%20%20thufir@dur:~/github/gradleScriptKotlin$%20gradle%20clean%20shadowJar;java%20-jar%20build/libs/gradleScriptKotlin.jar%20%20%20%3E%20Task%20:compileKotlin%20%20Using%20Kotlin%20incremental%20compilation%20%20%3E%20Task%20:shadowJar%20%20A%20problem%20was%20found%20with%20the%20configuration%20of%20task%20':shadowJar'.%20Registering%20invalid%20inputs%20and%20outputs%20via%20TaskInputs%20and%20TaskOutputs%20methods%20has%20been%20deprecated%20and%20is%20scheduled%20to%20be%20removed%20in%20Gradle%205.0.%20%20-%20No%20value%20has%20been%20specified%20for%20property%20'mainClassName'.%20The%20SimpleWorkResult%20type%20has%20been%20deprecated%20and%20is%20scheduled%20to%20be%20removed%20in%20Gradle%205.0.%20Please%20use%20WorkResults.didWork()%20instead.%20%20%20BUILD%20SUCCESSFUL%20in%201s%204%20actionable%20tasks:%204%20executed%20Hello%20gradle%20script%20Kotlin%20world!%20thufir@dur:~/github/gradleScriptKotlin$):

```
thufir@dur:~/github/gradleScriptKotlin$ 
thufir@dur:~/github/gradleScriptKotlin$ gradle clean shadowJar;java -jar build/libs/gradleScriptKotlin.jar 

> Task :compileKotlin 
Using Kotlin incremental compilation

> Task :shadowJar 
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':shadowJar'. Registering invalid inputs and outputs via TaskInputs and TaskOutputs methods has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0.
 - No value has been specified for property 'mainClassName'.
The SimpleWorkResult type has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use WorkResults.didWork() instead.


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
Hello gradle script Kotlin world!
thufir@dur:~/github/gradleScriptKotlin$
```

For the sake of brevity please refer to the [project itself](http://thufir@dur:~/github/gradleScriptKotlin$%20%20thufir@dur:~/github/gradleScriptKotlin$%20gradle%20clean%20shadowJar;java%20-jar%20build/libs/gradleScriptKotlin.jar%20%20%20%3E%20Task%20:compileKotlin%20%20Using%20Kotlin%20incremental%20compilation%20%20%3E%20Task%20:shadowJar%20%20A%20problem%20was%20found%20with%20the%20configuration%20of%20task%20':shadowJar'.%20Registering%20invalid%20inputs%20and%20outputs%20via%20TaskInputs%20and%20TaskOutputs%20methods%20has%20been%20deprecated%20and%20is%20scheduled%20to%20be%20removed%20in%20Gradle%205.0.%20%20-%20No%20value%20has%20been%20specified%20for%20property%20'mainClassName'.%20The%20SimpleWorkResult%20type%20has%20been%20deprecated%20and%20is%20scheduled%20to%20be%20removed%20in%20Gradle%205.0.%20Please%20use%20WorkResults.didWork()%20instead.%20%20%20BUILD%20SUCCESSFUL%20in%201s%204%20actionable%20tasks:%204%20executed%20Hello%20gradle%20script%20Kotlin%20world!%20thufir@dur:~/github/gradleScriptKotlin$) which only really consists of the build file and a kotlin script.

How to build a runnable ShadowJar with a gradle script Kotlin build file?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Building a self-executable jar with Gradle and Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26469365/8583692)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a fat JAR with Gradle Kotlin script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41794914/how-to-create-a-fat-jar-with-gradle-kotlin-script)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do you mean fatjar? 
If so, you could use shadow gradle plugin:

```
id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '2.0.2'
```

And if you want to make jar executable, you need also add `Main-class` to manifest (below example for main method in file `Applicaion.kt` with package `test`):

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'test.ApplicationKt'
    }
}
```

And with this you may run `jar` with command: `java -jar <your jar>`

Below I have include simple example. File `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '2.0.2'
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.2.21"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'test.ApplicationKt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    compile("org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.5")
}
```

File `test.Application.kt`:

```
package test

import org.simpleframework.xml.Element
import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root
import org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister

private val testXml = """
<feed>
   <entry>
        <id> someid </id>
        <published> somedate </published>
   </entry>

   <entry>
        <id> someid2 </id>
        <published> somedate2 </published>
   </entry>
</feed>
""".trimIndent()

@Root(name = "feed", strict = false)
data class Feed(
        @field:ElementList(name = "entry", inline = true)
        var entriesList: List<Entry>? = null
)

@Root(name = "entry", strict = true)
data class Entry(
        @field:Element(name = "id")
        var id: String? = null,

        @field:Element(name = "published")
        var published: String? = null
)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(testXml)

    val serializer = Persister()

    val example = serializer.read(Feed::class.java, testXml)

    println(example)
}
```

Run command: `gradle shadowJar`

And after try to run jar: `java -jar build/libs/shadow_test-all.jar`

**Update 2018-02-17**

`build.gradle.kts` version of file:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.Coroutines
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.2.21"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "2.0.2"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

tasks.withType<Jar> {
    manifest {
        attributes(mapOf(
                "Main-Class" to "test.ApplicationKt"
        ))
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    compile("org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.5")
}
```

Comment: thanks, very clear.  However, I'm looking for a `build.gradle.kts` file, versus `build.gradle` as above.

Answer (score 1):

the above answer uses a very old version, for newer versions:

add the plugin:

```
id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "6.1.0"
```

specify the main class:

```
application {
    mainClassName = "com.pkg.MainClassKt"
}
```

and lastly, specify the shadowJar task:

```
tasks {
    named<ShadowJar>("shadowJar") {
        archiveBaseName.set("jarFileNmae")
    }
}
```