# How to specify the entry point, Main-Class, for a FatJar using Gradle Kotlin DSL?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, uberjar, gradle-kotlin-dsl, shadowjar

How do I specify the `Main-Class` [attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) in the `ShadowJar` once it's [imported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48659849/262852)?

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.2.51"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "2.0.4"
}

group = "xxx.yyy"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

tasks.withType<ShadowJar> {
    baseName = "app"
    classifier = "inajar"
    version = "9"
    //main-class = "foobar"
}
```

Also, this build file might be out of date:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloKotlinWorld$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloKotlinWorld$ gradle clean ShadowJar

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloKotlinWorld$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloKotlinWorld$ java -jar build/libs/app-9-inajar.jar 
no main manifest attribute, in build/libs/app-9-inajar.jar
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloKotlinWorld$
```

project:

https://github.com/THUFIR/HelloKotlinWorld

Comment: Example `build.gradle.kts` to  build your `.jar` with gradle: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61373175/7747942

Answer (score 0):

build [file](https://github.com/THUFIR/HelloKotlinWorld):

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.2.51"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "2.0.4"
}

group = "xxx.yyy"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

tasks.withType<ShadowJar> {

    manifest.attributes.apply {
        put("Implementation-Title", "Gradle Jar File Example")
        //put("Implementation-Version" version)
        put("Main-Class", "HelloKotlinWorld.App")
    }


    baseName = "app"
    classifier = "inajar"
    version = "9"
}
```

runs:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloKotlinWorld$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloKotlinWorld$ gradle clean ShadowJar

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloKotlinWorld$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloKotlinWorld$ java -jar build/libs/app-9-inajar.jar 
Hello world.
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloKotlinWorld$
```

But I think it might be an out-of-date approach given the warning.