# Package Gradle as Zip

Tags: gradle, aws-lambda

How do I update this Gradle code into the Gradle(Kotlin) version?  I want to build my Java application so it can be deployed on AWS Lambda.

```
task packageJar(type: Zip) {
    into('lib') {
        from(jar)
        from(configurations.runtimeClasspath)
    }
}

build.dependsOn packageJar
```

The following code snippet is from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-package.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
plugins {
    java
}

tasks.register<Zip>("packageJar") {
    into("lib") {
        from(tasks.jar)
        from(configurations.runtimeClasspath)
    }
}

tasks.build {
    dependsOn("packageJar")
}
```

I've added the plugins block because otherwise *tasks.jar* and *configurations.runtimeClasspth* are not available.

Comment: I tried this and it compiled but the jar still contained the BOOT-INF directory that is not supported by AWS Lambda.  This response is what worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77669703/1304992