# What is the difference between registering and creating in Gradle Kotlin DSL

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

There are two methods of creating, i.e. tasks, in Gradle (5.0+):

```
tasks {
    val javadocJar by creating(Jar::class) {
        val javadoc by tasks

        from(javadoc)
        classifier = "javadoc"
    }
}
```

and

```
tasks {
    val javadocJar by registering(Jar::class) {
        val javadoc by tasks

        from(javadoc)
        classifier = "javadoc"
    }
}
```

Basically the same API, so what's the difference?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

See [using the container API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#using_the_container_api):

```kotlin
tasks.named("check")
tasks.register("myTask1")
tasks.named<JavaCompile>("compileJava")
tasks.register<Copy>("myCopy1")
```

> The above sample relies on the configuration avoidance APIs. If you need or want to eagerly configure or register container elements, simply replace `named()` with `getByName()` and `register()` with `create()`.

Difference between `creating` and `registering` (or `create` and `register` in Gradle versions prior to 5.0) is related to `Task Configuration Avoidance` new API, which is explained in details [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html) (see [this section](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html#sec:how_do_i_defer_creation)):

> **How do I defer task creation?**
>
> Effective task configuration avoidance requires build authors to change instances of `TaskContainer.create(java.lang.String)` to `TaskContainer.register(java.lang.String)`.
>
> …. The `create(…​)` API eagerly creates and configures tasks when it is called and should be avoided.
>
> Using `register(…​)` alone may not be enough to avoid all task configuration completely. You may need to change other code that configures tasks by name or by type, as explained in the following sections.

EDIT:
Also note that using `withType<T> { }` will immediately create and configure the task, and must be avoided using `withType<T>().configureEach {}` instead ([source](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html#sec:how_do_i_defer_configuration)).

> **How do I defer task configuration?**
>
> Eager APIs like `DomainObjectCollection.all(org.gradle.api.Action)` and `DomainObjectCollection.withType(java.lang.Class, org.gradle.api.Action)` will immediately create and configure any registered tasks. To defer task configuration, you will need to migrate to a configuration avoidance API equivalent. See the [table](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html#sec:old_vs_new_configuration_api_overview) below to identify the alternative.

Comment: In summary, `register is more efficient & will defer creation and configuration until required`. reference here: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core-api/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/NamedDomainObjectContainer.java#L88

Comment: And what is the difference between `registering` and `register` (or `creating` and `create`)?

Comment: @sschuberth there were a mistake in my initial answer;  `registering` and `creating` as Kotlin DSL specific features explained here in details : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#using_kotlin_delegated_properties

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer is great, but I want to add that if you want to actually use the reference created by `created` / `registering` call later, then there will be a difference in API. Compare

```
create<MavenPublication>("main") {
    …

    val sourcesJar by tasks.creating(Jar::class) {
        val sourceSets: SourceSetContainer by project
        from(sourceSets["main"].allJava)
        classifier = "sources"
    }

    artifact(sourcesJar)
}
```

and

```
create<MavenPublication>("main") {
    …

    val sourcesJar by tasks.registering(Jar::class) {
        val sourceSets: SourceSetContainer by project
        from(sourceSets["main"].allJava)
        classifier = "sources"
    }

    artifact(sourcesJar.get())
}
```

In case of registering, because it is lazy, you'll need an additional `.get()` call, or you'll get an exception:

```
* What went wrong:
Cannot convert the provided notation to an object of type MavenArtifact: task ':experiments:sourcesJar'.
The following types/formats are supported:
  - Instances of MavenArtifact.
  - Instances of AbstractArchiveTask, for example jar.
  - Instances of PublishArtifact
  - Maps containing a 'source' entry, for example [source: '/path/to/file', extension: 'zip'].
  - Anything that can be converted to a file, as per Project.file()
```

Comment: That's because `artifact(..)` does not support the lazy configuration API, could you please file a bug at https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues?

Comment: @eskatos Does Gradle still doesn't support lazy configuration API for `artifact(...)`?

Comment: It does not, see https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/7958

Comment: It does support it now (since Jan 2020; see the same issue).