# My output .jar gives an java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, meta-inf

The project can be run with 'Run' -> 'Run\'[PACKAGE.NAME].MainKt\'' in Intellij 
Idea IDE.

However, the I have tried several methods from Stack Overflow, the problem still exists as well as I built jar file, and when run the output jar file 
`jar -jar [JarFilePathInMyComputer].JarFile.jar`
,it throws an Exception as below

```sh
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
        at [PACKAGENAME].MainKt.main(Main.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
        ... 1 more
```

My dependencies are

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-runtime:1.2.71'
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5"
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.9'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

When I add artifacts, OutPut layout contains below kotlin libraries

```
Gradle: commons-code:commons-codec:1.11
Gradle: org.jetbrains.kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.21
Gradle: org.jetbrains.annaotations:13.0
Gradle: juniy.junit:4.12
Gradle: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.21
Gradle: org.jetbrains.kotlin-runtime:1.2.71
Gradle: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.21
Gradle: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.21
```

My MANIFEST.MF us

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: [PACKAGE.NAME].MainKt
Class-Path: [PACKAGE.NAME]
```

How can I fix it? I have tried several methods, but the same exception still throws.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building a self-executable jar with Gradle and Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26469365/5221149)

Answer (score 1):

You need to either add the kotlin runtime to your classpath when invoking java, or you need to build a fat jar file that packages the runtime in your jar file.  Personally, I like the fat jar option the best using the [shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) plugin.

```
plugins {
    ...
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow"
}
```

or you can use the `application` plugin, that creates a deployable package with windows and unix startup scripts that manage the classpath.

```
plugins {
    ...
    id "application"
}
```

There are some other approaches to creating a fat jar given in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469365/building-a-self-executable-jar-with-gradle-and-kotlin) (as Andreas suggested), and the [kotlin examples repository](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-examples/tree/master/gradle) has several projects that use the `application` plugin.