# Spring Boot build to .jar and run Could not resolve placeholder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I build my spring boot application to .jar file with:

```
./gradlew build
```

and when I want to run this app:

```
java -jar /build/libs/app.jar
```

I get error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.data.mongodb.host' in string value "${spring.data.mongodb.host}"
```

etc.

When I run this app in IntelliJ everything is ok.

My application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.username=newsAdminUser
spring.data.mongodb.password=abc123
spring.data.mongodb.database=newssystemservice

server.compression.enabled=true
server.compression.mime-types=application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain
```

What's the problem?

Comment: how are you reading the properties? from property file?

Comment: yes `application.properties`

Comment: Add more details, especially the `application.properties`, to question

Comment: Check if your jar file contains the property file, if not then you have to bundle the property file in jar. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724383/add-resources-config-files-to-your-jar-using-gradle for more info.

Comment: Yes, it's works. Thanks