# How to include all src/test/resources/** AND src/main/java/**/*.html in the test sourceset in gradle?

Tags: gradle

I have the following and thought it was 'adding' to my sourceSet but actually just modified it..

```
sourceSets {
    test {
        resources {
            srcDirs = ["src/main/java"]
            includes = ["**/*.html"]
        }
    }
}
```

What I really want is both src/test/resources/** and the above as well.  I don't want to exclude any files from src/test/resources though and the above is only including html from any directories I put there.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Try += operator instead of plain =

Comment: @Jk1 I am not sure I undertsand.  srcDirs += ["src/main/java"] ...ok, but when I do includes = ["**/*.html"] which would start excluding other stuff in src/test/resources that I want used, right?  I also don't want includes += ["**/*.html"] as that would imply **/* + **/*.html which doesn't seem useful I though?

Comment: @Jk1 perhaps you could elaborate with an example though?

Comment: @DeanHiller so, just to clarify, you want all html files from anywhere, aswell as everything below src/main/java and everything below src/test/resources?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will illustrate the technique using `main` (so it can be verified):

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
    myExtra {
        resources {
            srcDirs "src/main/java"
            includes = ["**/*.html"]
        }
    }
    main {
        resources {
            source myExtra.resources
        }
    }
}
```

Proof of concept via the command-line:

```
bash$ ls src/main/java
abc.html
xyz.txt

bash$ ls src/main/resources/
def.html
ijk.txt

bash$ gradle clean jar
bash$ jar tf build/libs/myexample.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
abc.html
def.html
ijk.txt
```

In your case, change `main` to `test`. This answer was discovered via the [Gradle doc for SourceDirectorySet](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/SourceDirectorySet.html). Interestingly, for 3.0, it contains a TODO:

> TODO - configure includes/excludes for individual source dirs

which implies that this work-around (via [this method](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/SourceDirectorySet.html#source(org.gradle.api.file.SourceDirectorySet))) is probably necessary.

Comment: grrrrrr, shucks @Michael Easter, it appeared to work great but broke the ./gradlew eclipse command with duplicate src/main/resources entries.  It nearly worked.  The gradle plugin still works but the gradle plugin is broken in that it doesn't port the -parameters setting to make sure params are compiled into the class files....just my luck :(.  The answer works for pure gradle though at least.  Anyone else, be careful as it may break your other stuff until gradlew eclipse is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I got your point. I tried this and it worked . Please take a look into it:

```
sourceSets {
    test {
        resources {
            srcDirs = ["src/main/java"]
            includes = ["**/*.html"]
        }
    }
}

sourceSets.test.resources.srcDir 'src/test/resources'
```

Add these in build.gradle.

Comment: @VyacheslavShvets what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I take that back.  This solution does NOT work as it ends up only including *.html files from src/test/resources.  I wanted src/test/resources/**** and src/main/java/**/*.html but this solution does not do that.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking whether or not to post this answer. So that if you are not satisfied with the previous answer, try the following hacky way (probably it will work with `eclipse` command):

```
apply plugin: 'java'

ConfigurableFileTree.metaClass.getAsSource = {
  def fileTrees = delegate.asFileTrees
  fileTrees.metaClass.getSrcDirTrees = {
    return delegate as Set
  }
  fileTrees as SourceDirectorySet
}

sourceSets {
  main {
    resources {
      srcDirs = []  // cleanup first
      source fileTree('src/main/java').include('**/*.html').asSource
      source fileTree('src/main/resources').asSource
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`srcDir`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.file.SourceDirectorySet.html#org.gradle.api.file.SourceDirectorySet:srcDir(java.lang.Object)) may be what you want. Here's an example:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir "src/main/resources"
            exclude "file-to-be-excluded"
            include "file-to-be-included"

            srcDir "src/main/java"
            include "**/*.html"

            srcDir "image-folder-in-root"
            include "**/*.png"
            include "**/*.jpg"
            exclude "**/*.xcf"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for, but it could be helpful for someone who finds this question:

I only wanted to have the test resources next to the sources. So I only need to exclude the sources.
In your case, perhaps you could exclude those which you would mind getting in the JAR and/or classpath.

None of the other answers worked for me, and this did work:

```
sourceSets {
    test {
        resources {
            srcDirs += "src/test/kotlin"
            excludes = ["**/*.kt"]
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle 6.3.