# Can I load resources from a Kotlin common module (multiplatform project)

Tags: kotlin, multiplatform

I am porting a maven JVM Kotlin project to a gradle multiplatform Kotlin project. After creating the default Kotlin multiplatform project from Intellij IDEA, I notice there is a `resources` directory, but the only way I know how to load from the resources directory is JVM specific `(this.javaClass.classLoader.getResourceAsStream(name)).`

My initial searching has not found a platform independent way to load a resource using Kotlin standard libraries. Is there something I am missing or is the `resources` directory useless in a common module?  The reason I need it is to load test data run in both  the `javascript` module and the jvm module.

Comment: Both [Gradle for jvm](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38982006/1941359) and [Webpack for js](http://stackoverflow.com/a/50739724/1941359) can be configured to use the common resources.

Answer (score 0):

It seams that the common/resource folder is ignored. I used an extra java module to share resources between projects.

Since your javascript module probably has to load the resources from a server, the way you access them in kotlin has to differ from the java module.

In the JS module you can use this command to load a file from server:

```
Request("https://pastebin.com/raw/p58mH6Cd").text().then(onFulfilled = {println(it)})
```

Comment: is it for Kotlin 1.2 or 1.3?

Comment: @Fluxparticle is correct. Resources are in Kotlin Multiplatform are platform dependend. As of Kotlin Multiplatform 1.6.x resources needs to be handles within the concrete platform code.