# Embed resources in kotlin js

Tags: javascript, kotlin

In kotlin jvm (or in java, for what it matter) one can read resource content through the resource input stream.

Is there a way to do it in kotlin js? 
Right now I'm requesting the resource with an ajax call but It would be best to have the resources automatically embedded in the compiled javascript to avoid further server roundtrips. 
I'm aware of the triple quote string literal but It's not what I'm looking for.

Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may add embedded data to javascript file by `webpack`. 
For example:

1) add file `test.json` to directory `src/main/resources` with content:

```
{
    "test123": 123
}
```

2) add directory `src/main/resources` to be resolve modules in `webpack`:

```
resolve: {
    modules: [
        path.resolve("src/main/resources")

    ]
}
```

3) add to main method code:

```
//require is external function: "external val require: dynamic"
println(JSON.stringify(require("test.json")))
```

And in output you will see: `{"test123":123}`

If you open webpack bundle, you will see that full file content of `test.json` is embedded to it like this:

```
function(t){t.exports={test123:123}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I did to include `svg` files embedded in the JS file in Kotlin 1.5.31 + Webpack 5. Let's suppose we have a SVG file named `star.svg` in your `src/jsMain/resources` folder.

`Project Root Folder/webpack.config.d/files.js` (The `files.js` name doesn't matter)

```js
config.module.rules.push(
    {
        test: /\.(svg)$/i,
        type: 'asset/source'
    }
);
```

Then in your code...

```
@JsModule("./star.svg")
@JsNonModule
external val star: dynamic

fun main() {
    console.log(star)
}
```

The print output is the contents of the `star.svg` file!

If you are curious about other available "type", check out https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/