# Manage generated resources for project in Gradle

Tags: gradle, resources

I have a Gradle project which has a lot of resources in the `/src/main/resources` folder. For performance reasons, some resources have to be generated from other resources at build time. So I split everything up into sub-projects:

```
/MainProj/src/main/java - The application
/MainProj/src/main/resources
/InternalProj/src/main/java - Code for generating additional resources for MainProj
/InternalProj/src/main/resources
```

When I run InternalProj using a special Gradle task, it generates some files to `/InternalProj/output` which I then copy to `/MainProj/src/main/resources`. Needless to say, this is really ugly and I'd like to know how to do this in a better way. Should I put it somewhere into build or directly into `/MainProj/src/main/resources`? Maybe use a symlink?

---

## Edit

I now use a relative symlink from `/src/main/generated-resources` to `/build/something` and so far it works fine. But now I have a different problem: I have task `A` that generates some resources and task `B` that depends on those resources and thus on `A`. If I run `gradle B` or `gradle A B`, `B` will still fail since the resources generated by `A` didn't get updated into its build folder. How can I force Gradle to update the resources?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `output` file to the main source set of the `InternalProj`:

Example Groovy Code:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs "src/main/resources", "output"
        }
    }
}
```

Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38982006/3708426

Comment: I'd like these resources to be deleted with the `clean`, so in which of the `build`-subfolders should I put them?

Comment: The whole `build` directory gets cleaned when you run `clean`. So feel free to create your own.