# How To Make a Folder Appear When Unzipping Jar File Using Gradle?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

Hi I am fairly new to Spring boot and Gradle. My question is how do I get a folder that I currently have in my Spring boot project to appear when I open up the jar file?

- I have a folder with bash scripts in my spring boot project called: bashScriptFolder
- its directory structure is src/main/bashScriptFolder

whenever I deploy my jar file into a linux server and open up the jar file the bashScriptFolder does not appear. Im assuming I have to make a gradle task for this to happen but Im not sure how to do that. Ive been trying to look at different stackover flow pages for this problem but I cant find 1 quite clear post to do this maybe im not wording my search right. I would really appreciate the help guys.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `bashScriptFolder` inside `src/main/resources` and `jar` task will add it by default. Or use `from - include` in `jar` task configuration, e.g. like here: [Add resources, config files to your jar using gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724383/add-resources-config-files-to-your-jar-using-gradle)