# How do you add text files to the classpath in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, typesafe-config

I'm using the [Typesafe Config](https://github.com/lightbend/config) library in a Kotlin project built with Gradle 6.  How do I tell Gradle that there's a directory (or two, or specific files) with HOCON files that need to be added to the runtime classpath so Config can find them?

(SO is now suggesting that I edit the question to make it clear that the answer in [Add resources, config files to your jar using gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724383/add-resources-config-files-to-your-jar-using-gradle) isn't relevant.  It's not relevant because there's nothing about jar files in my question.)

Comment: You put the files under src/main/resources, like all the other classpath resources. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_project_layout

Comment: @JBNizet no, since it assumes there's a jar file being generated.  That's not the case if you just run your code.

Comment: @JBNizet except that files in src/main/resources aren't added to the directories that are on the runtime classpath.  By default, the only directory in the classpath that's in your project is build/classes/kotlin/main, and gradle doesn't copy files from src/main/resources to there.

Comment: I should think that this is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38982006/1005481

Comment: Yes, resources end up in the runtime classpath whether you use Gradle to run your code or IntelliJ, and whether or not you create a jar. What makes you think they don't? What are you doing? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead?